# Javac is not recognized. (Already set path)

Tags: java, command-line, path

guys, I can't compile or run any of my programs in the command line. I set the location of my `java.exe` in paths but that did nothing. Any other fixes?

My path looks like this:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_40\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\NVIDIA
>   Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;D:\bin;D:\QuickTime\QTSystem\;D:\Python;D:\Python\Lib;D:\Python\DLLs;D:\Python\Lib\lib-tk;

Comment: jre != jdk.  You need to download and install the "Java Development Kit" or JDK

Comment: okay lemme give it a shot. i had it installed earlier but it wasn't working. Brb.

Comment: If it is installed, make sure that it's if the `path`

Comment: @MadProgrammer It worked. I had all of this installed and it stopped working for some reason so I did a clean install, but i forgot to install the JDK. Thank ya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the JDK path

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\lib;

Comment: It worked. I had all of this installed and it stopped working for some reason so I did a clean install, but i forgot to install the JDK. Thank ya.